# FCM Authorization always fails

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Today i wanted to switch from GCM to FCM so i set up everything needed and wanted to implement the server side code. I used the [gcm4j](https://github.com/phonedeck/gcm4j) library and changed it so that the adress goes to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`.

So im doing the following:

```
FCM fcm = new FCMDefault(new FCMConfig().withKey(FCMGlobals.FCM_API_KEY));

FCMRequest request = new FCMRequest().withRegistrationId(android.getRegistration())
    // .withCollapseKey(collapseKey)
    .withDelayWhileIdle(true)
    .withDataItem(FCMGlobals.FCM_PARAM_CODE, code)
    .withDataItem(FCMGlobals.FCM_PARAM_USER_ID, "" + user.getId())
    .withDataItem(FCMGlobals.FCM_PARAM_ADDITION, "" + addition);

ListenableFuture<FCMResponse> responseFuture = fcm.send(request);

Futures.addCallback(responseFuture, new FutureCallback<FCMResponse>() {

    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        log.error(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FCMResponse response) {
        log.info(response.toString());
    }
});
```

The implementation for that is:

```
protected FCMResponse executeRequest(FCMRequest request) throws IOException {
    byte[] content = this.objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(request);

    HttpURLConnection conn = this.connectionFactory.open(this.fcmUrl);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", getAuthorization(request));
    conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(content.length);

    LoggerFactory.getLogger("FCMDefaultAbstract").info("Authorization: " + conn.getRequestProperty("Authorization"));
    LoggerFactory.getLogger("FCMDefaultAbstract").info("Content-Type: " + conn.getRequestProperty("Content-Type"));
    LoggerFactory.getLogger("FCMDefaultAbstract").info("send: " + new String(content));

    try (OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream()) {
        IOUtils.write(content, outputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FCMNetworkException("Error sending HTTP request to FCM", e);
    }

    FCMResponse response;

    try (InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream()) {
        response = this.objectMapper.readValue(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream), FCMResponse.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try (InputStream inputStreamError = conn.getErrorStream()) {
            String str = inputStreamError != null ? IOUtils.toString(inputStreamError) : "No error details provided";
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode < 500) {
                throw new FCMNetworkException(conn.getResponseCode(), str.trim(), e);
            } else {
                throw new FCMNetworkException(conn.getResponseCode(), str.trim(), checkForRetryInResponse(conn), e);
            }
        }
    }

    response.setRequest(request);
    response.setRetryAfter(checkForRetryInResponse(conn));

    Iterator<String> iteratorId = request.getRegistrationIds().iterator();
    Iterator<FCMResult> iteratorResponse = response.getResults().iterator();

    while (iteratorId.hasNext() && iteratorResponse.hasNext()) {
        iteratorResponse.next().setRequestedRegistrationId(iteratorId.next());
    }

    if (iteratorId.hasNext()) {
        LOG.warn("Protocol error: Less results than requested registation IDs");
    }

    if (iteratorResponse.hasNext()) {
        LOG.warn("Protocol error: More results than requested registation IDs");
    }

    return response;
}
```

Here the log output:

```
FCMDefaultAbstract                      Authorization: null
FCMDefaultAbstract                      Content-Type:application/json
FCMDefaultAbstract                      send: {"registration_ids":["dMpvzp*************************************2lRsSl_5lFET2"],"data":{"CODE":"201","USER_ID":"1","ADDITION":"1468083549493"},"delay_while_idle":true}
FCM                                     FCMNetworkException: HTTP 401: No error details provided
```

The `Authorization` header is not null in fact. it is correctly set with my FCM API Key. Only the `HTTPUrlConnection` implementation says to return null if someone trys to access `Authorization` key.

As you can see i am not able to connect with FCM. The Code `401` means that authentication failed.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that you are using a `server type` API-KEY, and not a `client` or `browser` API-KEY.

If you are using Firebase you can find the API-KEY in
*Project Settings > Cloud Messaging*

If you are using cloud console, or you are not sure which key you are using, 
you can generate a new key through through https://console.cloud.google.com

Quoting the documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials

> **Server key:**    A server key that authorizes your app server for access to
>   Google services, including sending messages via Firebase Cloud
>   Messaging. [...]
>   **Important:** Do not include the server key anywhere in your client code.
>   Also, make sure to use only server keys to authorize your app server.
>   Android, iOS, and browser keys are rejected by FCM.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. It is a server key. At least it is the title of the key under `Project Settings > Cloud Messaging`. So it has to work doesnt it? Do i need the Sender-ID anywhere? I guess not because `getToken()` in the android implementation does not take any parameters.

Comment: yes. it should. you can try to re-generate it accessing the project from https://console.cloud.google.com > api > credentials.
But at this point it might be an issue in your library.

Comment: Oh. The Firebase Console is telling me that i have a server key. The cloud console you posted is actually telling me, that it is an android key oO.

Comment: Glad we found the issue. If you don't mind please report the problem via https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/ so that the right team can investigate it. Thanks.